# Как получить значение responseText из вне

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

есть код

```
function getXHR() {
  var xmlHttp;
  try {
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    } catch (E) {
      xmlHttp = false;
    }
  }
  if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  return xmlHttp;
}

function getData (url) {
    var xmlHttp = getXHR();
    var json;
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
          return JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      }
    };

    xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}

var temperatureData = getData('data/temperature.json');
console.log(temperatureData)
```

temperatureData undefined, понимаю, что запрос асинхронный, но как все таки засунуть JSON.parse(this.responseText) в переменную без промисов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На момент вызова console.log(temperatureData), переменная temperatureData еще не получена и равняется undefined. Такова особенность асинхронной работы js. что-бы присвоить в эту переменную переменную надо

```
if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
      const temperatureData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      return temperatureData;
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но такой вариант не подходит, нужно создать именно несколько переменных, которым присваивается функция, которая возвращает разные данные, а так как XTMLHttpRequest асинхронный, то переменная undefined